# How to host local project to gitHub?

Tags: github

I created a folder, say `test`, where I'll put all my code for the project and then I `git init` in that folder. Now, I want to host that project on gitHub.

What are the next steps that I should perform so that my code will be hosted to gitHub and I can sync up my code to gitHub repository?

Comment: git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git ....
git push origin master .....

Comment: I did that but after hitting `git push origin master` it's resulting into following error: `error: The requested URL returned error: 403 while accessing https://github.com/user/test1.git/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed`

Comment: Actually, before doing `git push origin master`, you must have atleast one file commited. Thanks Rahul!! Problem is solved.

Comment: yup `git add .` : `git commit -m "init"` . and then do the push .
welcome .